# YouTube API video uploads stop after 5-10 chunks (Server to server)

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I just started playing around with the YouTube Data API and struggled with chunk size.

Here is how the chunk size is set in the PHP code sample from the documentation:

```
// Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
// reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
// value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
```

After some more testing I found out that **YouTube only accepted the first 5-10 chunks**, then the upload stops (sometimes it continues 2 minutes later, but just for a few more chunks, then stops forever).

I then increased the chunk size to 10MB (10 * 1024 * 1024) but still had the same problem. Files larger than 50-100MB just abort after a few chunks.

Now that I've set the chunk size to 100MB (100 * 1024 * 1024) it's working fine so far, but I haven't tested with 1GB+ files.

**Why is this happening and how can I fix this?**

I can't imagine it's best practice to send 5GB chunks if I want to upload 20GB videos, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Resumable Uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol). Compared to simple uploads, resumable uploads was designed for larger files.

> Using resumable uploads is especially useful in any of the following
>   cases:
>
> - You are transferring large files.
> - The likelihood of a network interruption is high.
> - Uploads are originating from a device with a low-bandwidth or unstable Internet connection, such as a mobile device.
>
> To start a resumable video upload, send a POST request to the
>   following URL. In the URL, set the part parameter value to the
>   appropriate value for your request. Remember that the parameter value
>   identifies the parts the contain properties that you are setting, and
>   it also identifies the parts that you want the API response to
>   include. Parameter values in the request URL must be URL-encoded.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=PARTS
```